# Compiling a basic openCL program error: unresolved includes inside cl.hpp

Tags: c++, opencl, intel

I am new to coding in openCL and am following the tutorial found here: https://www.marcusbannerman.co.uk/index.php/research/teaching-resources/77-supercomputing-on-graphics-cards-an-introduction-to-opencl-and-the-c-bindings.html and am running into issues.

This is my first code I am attempting in openCL and so far having troubles. I have succesfully placed targeted the libraries in my IDE (netbeans) as they come up as an option when writing code, but I get an error with the cl.hpp file saying that there are unresolved includes inside .

Errors:

```
main.cpp:7:18: cl.hpp: No such file or directory
main.cpp: In function `int main()':
main.cpp:24: error: `cl' has not been declared
main.cpp:24: error: `Context' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:24: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
main.cpp:24: error: expected `;' before "context"
main.cpp:27: error: `cl' has not been declared
main.cpp:27: error: `Sources' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:27: error: expected `;' before "source"
main.cpp:28: error: `source' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:31: error: `cl' has not been declared
main.cpp:31: error: `Program' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:31: error: expected `;' before "program"
main.cpp:34: error: `cl' has not been declared
main.cpp:34: error: `Device' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
main.cpp:34: error: template argument 2 is invalid
main.cpp:35: error: invalid type in declaration before '=' token
main.cpp:35: error: `context' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:35: error: `CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:35: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
main.cpp:39: error: `program' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:41: error: `cl' has not been declared
main.cpp:41: error: `Error' has not been declared
main.cpp:41: error: invalid catch parameter
main.cpp:44: error: `err' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:46: error: `CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:46: error: invalid types `int[int]' for array subscript
main.cpp:52: error: `cl' has not been declared
main.cpp:52: error: `Kernel' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:52: error: expected `;' before "kernel"
main.cpp:55: error: `cl' has not been declared
main.cpp:55: error: `CommandQueue' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:55: error: expected `;' before "cmdQ"
main.cpp:60: error: `cl_float' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:60: error: template argument 1 is invalid
main.cpp:60: error: template argument 2 is invalid
main.cpp:60: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h: In instantiation of `std::back_insert_iterator<int>':
main.cpp:61:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:363: error: `int' is not a class, struct, or union type
main.cpp: In function `int main()':
main.cpp:64: error: `cl' has not been declared
main.cpp:64: error: `Buffer' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:64: error: expected `;' before "inputBuffer"
main.cpp:67: error: `cl' has not been declared
main.cpp:67: error: expected `;' before "outputBuffer"
main.cpp:73: error: `kernel' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:73: error: `inputBuffer' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:74: error: `outputBuffer' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:77: error: `cl' has not been declared
main.cpp:77: error: `KernelFunctor' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:77: error: expected `;' before "func"
main.cpp:80: error: `func' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:86: error: template argument 1 is invalid
main.cpp:86: error: template argument 2 is invalid
main.cpp:86: error: invalid type in declaration before '(' token
main.cpp:86: error: request for member `size' in `input', which is of non-class type `int'
main.cpp:89: error: `cmdQ' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:89: error: request for member `size' in `input', which is of non-class type `int'
main.cpp:89: error: invalid types `int[int]' for array subscript
main.cpp:92: error: request for member `size' in `input', which is of non-class type `int'
main.cpp:93: error: invalid types `int[size_t]' for array subscript
main.cpp:93: error: invalid types `int[size_t]' for array subscript
main.cpp:93: error: invalid types `int[size_t]' for array subscript
main.cpp:94: error: invalid types `int[size_t]' for array subscript
main.cpp:94: error: invalid types `int[size_t]' for array subscript
main.cpp:99: error: `cl' has not been declared
main.cpp:99: error: `Error' has not been declared
main.cpp:99: error: invalid catch parameter
main.cpp:105:2: warning: no newline at end of file
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h: In function `_OutputIterator std::generate_n(_OutputIterator, _Size, _Generator) [with _OutputIterator = std::back_insert_iterator<int>, _Size = unsigned int, _Generator = int (*)()]':
main.cpp:61:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1006: error: no match for 'operator=' in '(&__first)->std::back_insert_iterator<_Container>::operator* [with _Container = int]() = __gen()'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:338: note: candidates are: std::back_insert_iterator<int>& std::back_insert_iterator<int>::operator=(const std::back_insert_iterator<int>&)
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:66: recipe for target `build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Thomas/SkyDrive/Documents/Research Documents/openCL/Testing/helloworld'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target `.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Thomas/SkyDrive/Documents/Research Documents/openCL/Testing/helloworld'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target `.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

Let me know if you need more info! Any help on setting it up on windows properly would be appreciated!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//The OpenCL C++ bindings, with exceptions
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#include <cl.hpp>

const size_t problemSize = 1024;

//The compute kernel we will run
const char * kernelSrc = 
  "__kernel void squareArray(__global float* input, "
  "                          __global float* output)"
  "{"
  "  output[get_global_id(0)] = input[get_global_id(0)] * input[get_global_id(0)];"
  "}";

int main()
{
  try {
    /***************     OpenCL Initialisation      ***************/
    //Open a context to run the openCL kernel in
    cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU);

    //Gather all the kernel sources for the OpenCL program
    cl::Program::Sources source;
    source.push_back(std::make_pair(kernelSrc, strlen(kernelSrc)));

    //Make an OpenCL program
    cl::Program program(context, source);

    //Get all the available devices in the context
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices 
      = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();

    //Build the kernel sources for all devices in the context
    try {
      program.build(devices);
    }
    catch (cl::Error& err)
      {
    //Get the build log for the first device
    std::cerr << "Building failed, " << err.what() << "(" << err.err() << ")" 
          << "\nRetrieving build log\n" 
          << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(devices[0])
          << "\n";
    return -1;
      }

    //Get the squareArray kernel to use in calculations
    cl::Kernel kernel(program, "squareArray");

    //Make a queue to put jobs on the first compute device
    cl::CommandQueue cmdQ(context, devices[0]);

    /***************   Preparing the data buffers   ***************/

    //Create a vector of random input values
    std::vector<cl_float> input;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(input), problemSize, rand);

    //Start copying this data to the graphics card
    cl::Buffer inputBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_float) * input.size(), &input[0]);

    //Make a buffer to hold the output of the kernel
    cl::Buffer outputBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(cl_float) * input.size());


    /***************  Running on the graphics card  ***************/

    //Set the two arguments of the squareArray kernel
    kernel.setArg(0, inputBuffer);
    kernel.setArg(1, outputBuffer);

    //Get a Functor which will run the kernel on every input item in blocks of 64 threads
    cl::KernelFunctor func = kernel.bind(cmdQ, cl::NDRange(input.size()), cl::NDRange(64));

    //Run the kernel and wait for it to finish
    func().wait();


    /***************  Checking the outputted data   ***************/

    //Make a buffer to hold the outputted data
    std::vector<cl_float> output(input.size());

    //Request a blocking copy of the data from the graphics card
    cmdQ.enqueueReadBuffer(outputBuffer, true, 0, sizeof(cl_float) * input.size(), &output[0]);

    //Now check the answer
    for (size_t i(0); i < input.size(); ++i)
      if (input[i]*input[i] != output[i]) 
    std::cout << "Found a mistake " << input[i] << "^2 != " << output[i] << "\n";

    std::cout << "Finished!\n";
    return 0;
  }
  catch (cl::Error& err)
    {
      std::cerr << "An OpenCL error occured, " << err.what()
        << "\nError num of " << err.err() << "\n";
      return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need your actual code and actual error messages.

Comment: Hey there, new to this. I have included code and errors

Comment: You need to make sure your compiler's build flags include the directory that contains your cl.hpp header-file. All of the rest of these errors (or most, probably) are coming from the fact that your compiler is not able to locate the header-file you need.

Comment: I have done this, the IDE spits out a seperate error on the editor screen saying:"There are unresolved includes inside <cl.hpp>" for some reason the error still comes up.

Comment: Okay, but at least you're finding cl.hpp, let's see those error messages.

Comment: Ah I have solved the problem. Over lunch I converted my code over to visual studio and was able to get it working. I had a typo in my linker. Here is a good tutorial to set up for the future if anyone asks http://kode-stuff.blogspot.ca/2012/11/setting-up-opencl-in-visual-studio_1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem specifically related to OpenCL.

You need to give the directory of the OpenCL headers to your compiler.
Assuming you're using GCC or Clang, use the `-I` flag. Something like this should work (please check the directory using `locate`):

> g++ -I/usr/include/CL ...

Comment: Yeah, this ended up being a simple typo in my linker (using windows btw). COnverted over to VS using this tutorial http://kode-stuff.blogspot.ca/2012/11/setting-up-opencl-in-visual-studio_1.html